# How to make Microsoft Keyboard special keys run osascript commands on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, osascript

I'm trying to make (1) special key open new terminal window.

I bound it to file `/Users/taw/bin/new_term`, which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd ."'
```

This does the trick, except it also opens a Terminal window with this (even though Terminal.app is configured to always close windows when processes finish):

```
Last login: Thu Mar 11 19:41:29 on ttys000
/Users/taw/bin/new_term ; exit;
~$ /Users/taw/bin/new_term ; exit;
tab 1
logout

[Process completed]
```

How do I make it all work correctly? (possibly using a way different that what I've been attempting so far)

Answer (score 1):

Because the Microsoft IntelliType Pro software on OS X uses the `open` command to run whatever you ask it to, it can be difficult to get it to execute arbitrary AppleScript code.

I found that while shell scripts and the like don't work, if you create an Automator (not AppleScript) application with a single Action `Run AppleScript` you can then point IntelliType to run your Automator Application.  Be sure you create an Application, not a Workflow.

I wanted a favorites key to control iTunes, so I used the following inside my `Run AppleScript` Action, which worked.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "iTunes" to next track

    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your special key execute `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal` instead.

(Out of curiosity, how are you binding a key to a command?)

Edit:

I try to keep anything Microsoft away from Mac OS, because they don't really seem to grok the Mac way. The fact that it's using `open` for everything is proof of this.

So, if I were you, I'd rip out the Microsoft keyboard driver, and use Spark instead:

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/mac-platform/reviews/30244.aspx

If you really want to use AppleScript to do what you're doing, perhaps this will be of use:

http://lambie.org/2007/11/03/tabs-in-terminal-using-applescript-on-leopard/

You could also snag some of the AppleScript from the latter link and trigger it with a hotkey using Spark.

Comment: Microsoft Keyboard drivers let me bind special keys (or any keys) to arbitrary file or URL. I think it tries to open the file using generic open command.

Starting /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal seems to start a new process - not what I want. And then it opens the same window [Process completed] window.

Comment: Spark doesn't see special keys on Microsoft Keyboard at all.

Comment: So then don't use the special keys. Use command-control-0 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the options to start a program or execute a script without opening Terminal I describe [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/236590/how-to-run-something-at-mac-os-x-by-clicking-on-the-desktop-item/236828#236828).

---

To open a new terminal window, or just Terminal with a default window, you can try to adapt [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/218816/os-x-terminal-make-a-shortcut-that-opens-to-a-specific-folder/218863#218863).